# Unknown error in python pptx module add_picture

Tags: python, python-pptx

I've been trying to input a series of pictures onto every slide on a powerpoint presentation. I type in the image path, and the relevant dimensions, but I get an error which I don't understand.

```
    for k in xrange(0, len(prs.slides)):
        img_path = os_path + str(k+1) + '.png'
        left = Cm(1.21)
        top = Cm(4.72)
        width = Cm(5)
        height = Cm(5)
        pic = prs.slides[k].shapes.add_picture(img_path, left, top, width, height)
```

This error then appears:

```
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1819, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:116494)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1700, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115040)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1040, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:109165)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103404)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105058)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 613, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103967)
  lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: EntityRef: expecting ';', line 3, column 31
```

There is definitely a file that corresponds to the img_path, so I'm not sure what else is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed this.

My img_path in my documents included an & in the file name - I changed where the image was located (to a folder without an &) and it worked.

Comment: Good catch Tom. This is probably something that should be fixed. The filename (where available) is included in the image information and written to the XML. I expect the name is not being escaped before writing. If you add an issue on the python-pptx GitHub issues list we'll get this fixed up.